# iOS - Shortcut for jumping to definition in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, shortcut, xcode9-beta

In previous Xcode version , I could jump to definition with simple 
**Cmd + click** on that method/variable . 
But in Xcode 9, I feel uncomfortable to jump to definition .

Does anyone has a better solution for jumping to definition in Xcode 9 ?

I am tired of selecting options from dropdown list.

Comment: Great Question!!!

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Ashish and Ghulam's answers were great but it still kinda bugged me that things had changed and I couldn't jump to definition as before. Then I found this...

*Xcode9Beta2-Preferences->Navigation->Command-click on Code:->Jump To Definition*:

[image: Xcode9Beta2-Preferences->Navigation->Command-click on Code:->Jump To Definition]

Comment: This answer is good. I changed it to the old way. I have been using CMD+Left Click for decades.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `right mouse click` is identical to `control+click`, so now you can `select code structure` (show context menu) by pressing `cmd + right mouse click`.

Comment: And to go back to where you came from: ctrl-cmd-left arrow

Answer (score 31):

**Solution 1:**

- Go to Xcode menu
- Click on Preferences
- Select Navigation Tab from Top
- Select Command-click on Code
- Change to "Jumps to Definition"

[image: As you can see in this screenshot]

**Solution 2:**
Use

**Ctrl + ⌘ + Left click**

Answer (score 24):

There is short cut displayed on drop down menu, just use-

**1. Control, Command and left mouse button**

OR

**2. Command plus Right Mouse Click**

instead of *command left mouse button*.

Comment: Command-right-click seems to be what I wanted.  It's dumb that they changed it -- I never want any of the stuff in the popup menu.

Comment: My issue with command+control+left click is that it's extremely inconvenient for a left-handed person, since control is only on the left side of the MBP keyboard. In such light, it seems not well thought-out to make this the default after so long.

Answer (score 20):

In Xcode 9 Beta, you can go definition by **Cmd + Right Click**

Answer (score 7):

Standard hot key for jump to definition is ctrl+cmd+j. Set cursor to the class/method you are interested in and press this buttons to switch to declaration. Also you can try to press ctrl+opt+cmd+j. In this case definition will be opened in assistant editor

Comment: i'd say that should be the accepted answer - why take your hands off the keyboard? :)

Answer (score 6):

If dont like to use mouse click(I certainly don't like) you could use

> Command + Ctrl + J

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 9 both of these work:

**⌘ + Right Click**

OR

**⌘⌃ + Click**

Answer (score 4):

When I <kbd>⌘-click</kbd> on a symbol in Xcode 9 I see

[image]

That means you have to <kbd>⌃⌘-click</kbd> on the symbol to skip the popup.

---

Nevertheless there is even a keyboard shortcut:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how Cmd + Option + Left Click worked for you guys, but the shortcut (at least for me) was **Cmd + Ctrl + Left Click**.
I've tried on both Apple keyboard and MacBook keyboard and this is the one that did it.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 9 Beta, it has been changed to **Cmd + Ctrl + Left Click**.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution to your question: `Ctrl + ⌘ + Left click`**

> Xcode >> Preference >> Key Bindings >> Here is list of all short cuts
>   of Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the answer from user8315745, not this one.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting everything under the Derived data and re-opening Xcode fixed everything for me.