# XCode 9.0 "Jump to definition" context menu hangs frequently

Tags: ios, xcode, navigation, syntax-highlighting, xcode9

I'm looking for a solution to XCode9 frequently hanging up with a spinner when showing context menu using command> click. If I close the edited file, the spinner window disappears, but I still cannot jump to definition.

**How do I fix my XCode's ability to jump to class definition?**

I've [attempted to change the shortcut to the one provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497436/ios-shortcut-for-jumping-to-definition-in-xcode-9), but in this case nothing happens at all when command-clicking on a custom class.

[image]

Comment: It’s was funny question... normally it’s depends on your project code and RAM speed. My system it’s working fine.. it’s good apple introduced new things to speed up the work ..

Comment: I know this is silly, but for me, restarting XCode worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is weird... I was about to suggest you to change the shortcut but you already did that... Do you have Xcode 8 installed too? The only thing I can guess is you may have a conflict between "Xcodes", check your command tools also, not sure if related but running out of options without further information...

Xcode 9 came out with a lot of bugs though but this is not a popular one right now..